# ValueError: time data 'dateConstat' does not match format

Tags: odoo

my code:

```
annee_now    =   datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
 dateConstat =   fields.Date(default= fields.Date.today())
 fiche_emi_Struc=self.env['conformite.fiche'].search_count([(datetime.datetime.strptime(("dateConstat"),"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y"),'=',annee_now)])
```

my message error:
ValueError: time data 'dateConstat' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
How Resolve it?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this:

```py
annee_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
dateConstat = fields.Date.today()
fiche_emi_Struc = self.env['conformite.fiche'].search_count([
  ((dateConstat).strftime("%Y"), '=', annee_now)
])
```

Comment: thanks keval Mehta for your help but I have this message after change AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Check the changes.

Comment: Keval Mehta with this change I have this message :NameError: global name 'dateConstat' is not defined